# Proving that the function $xy(-ln(x^2 + y^2))^{1/2}$ is $C^1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to prove that the function $f: A\to\mathbb{R}$, $A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}$

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}xy(-\ln{(x^2 + y^2)})^{1/2} & 0<x^2 + y^2 <1 \\ 0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$$

is $C^1 (A)$ and that exist $f_{x,x}$, $f_{yy} \in C(A)$. Then I have to determine if $f \in C^2 (A)$

I started proving that $f\in C^{1} (A)$: for sure we know that $f \in C^1(A\setminus \{0\})$, so we have to show that the partial derivatives are continuous in {$0,0$}. In order to do it we have to study the limits $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0.0)} -\frac{y[(x^2+y^2)\ln{(x^2+y^2)}+x^2]}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{-\ln{(x^2+y^2)}}}$$

and

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0.0)} -\frac{x[(x^2+y^2)\ln{(x^2+y^2)}+y^2]}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{-\ln{(x^2+y^2)}}}$$

If this limit is $0$ then $f\in C^1(A)$. I can't find if this limit is $0$. Can you help me with this limit and the other requests? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $A= \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Sorry, I edit. $A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 < 1\}$

Answer (score 0):

*HINT*

$-\frac{y((x^2+y^2)\ln{(x^2+y^2)}+x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{-\ln{(x^2+y^2)}}}=
-y\sqrt{-\ln{(x^2+y^2)}}-\frac{yx^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{-\ln{(x^2+y^2)}}}$

Then take polar coordinates:$$x=r\cos{\theta}$$ $$y=r\sin{\theta}$$

and use that $$\lim_{r \to 0^+}-r\sqrt{-\ln{(r)}}=0$$  $$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r}{\sqrt{-\ln{r^2}}}=0$$

Thus the limit is zero.

Use the same argument for the second limit.

Comment: Can you explain why that inequality is true?

Comment: @brt22..in $\ln{(x^2+y^2)+x^2)}$ what  do you mean because you have a problem in parenthesis..edit your question please

Comment: I edited.. I also added the second limit to do in order to prove that $f\in C^1 (A)$

Comment: @brt22...i edited my answer according to your last edit

Comment: Thank you, now how can I prove that the second order derivatives exist?

Comment: @brt22 that's another question..which you have to included in different posts..and for computing the second derivatives wil need many calculations...and also you have to find compute the first derivatives at zero,for comptuting the second derivatives

Answer (score 0):

I'll deal with the first expression. (If this one $\to 0$ then the second one $\to 0$ by symmetry.)

The term $\sqrt{-\ln{(x^2+y^2)}}$ downstairs $\to \infty.$ So it is helping us. Perhaps we can just omit it and the thing will still $\to 0.$ It's worth a try. So consider

$$\tag 1 \frac{y[(x^2+y^2)\ln{(x^2+y^2)}+x^2]}{x^2+y^2}$$

Slap absolute values on everything and use the facts that $|y|\le (x^2+y^2)^{1/2},$ $x^2 \le x^2 + y^2.$ Let's also write $r= (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.$ Then the absolute value of $(1)$ is no more that

$$\frac{r[r^2|\ln{r^2}|+r^2]}{r^2} = r|\ln{r^2}| +r.$$

Now you're back in one variable, needing only to show the last expression $\to 0$ as $r\to 0^+.$

Comment: Thank you, I can do the same with the other limit. Now I have to say if $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ exist... what does it mean? Maybe I have to calculate the second order derivative and prove that they are continuous?